# DirectX Screenshot Not Working?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I trying to take a screenshot using DirectX, and then save it to file.
But when the below code executes, I get a totally black .png sized(width/height) as target DirectX app. What am I doing wrong?

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

ID3D11Texture2D* pBuffer;
ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBufferStaging = NULL;

pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBuffer);

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC td;
pBuffer->GetDesc(&td);
td.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
td.BindFlags = 0;
td.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
td.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
td.MiscFlags &= D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE;

pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&td, NULL, &pBackBufferStaging);
pContext->CopyResource(pBackBufferStaging, pBuffer);

D3DX11SaveTextureToFile(pContext, pBackBufferStaging, D3DX11_IFF_PNG, L"D:\\screen.png");

pBackBufferStaging->Release();
pBuffer->Release();
```

`pSwapChain` is pointer to `IDXGISwapChain`, `pDevice` is pointer to `ID3D11Device`, and `pContext` is pointer to `ID3D11DeviceContext`. They are all setup correctly but the resulting screenshot is still black.

### Update #1

Error checking shows nothing. All functions are successfully executed. While in DirectX 11 "Hello world", everything works fine. What am I doing wrong? I am trying to screen shot a World of Tanks game.

### Update #2

On DirectX 9, my approach works fine - Heartstone produces working screenshot.

Comment: Error checking is *not* optional.

Comment: @HansPassant the question was not about this. And as I said, they are hooked correctly. So the question is what's wrong here

Comment: Well, you have no error checking and that's exactly why you don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe okey, with error checking, no errors occurred but screenshot is still black.

Comment: WoT game? some DRM protection is in the way perhaps - is the behavior the same when you just use print screen?

Comment: @Ap31 no. On Print Screen in  full-screen opened WoT I got Desktop screenshot. P.S. Screenshot of Heartstone done ok, but that`s DirectX9.

Comment: D3DX11 is deprecated as is the legacy DirectX SDK (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx)), so you may well be hitting some latent bug in that code. Take a look at the [ScreenGrab](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ScreenGrab) code in either [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) or [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex). For example, the legacy D3DX11 code can't save MSAA textures, while ScreenGrab handles the required resolve for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass the following texture description to CreateTexture2D:

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC td;
pBuffer->GetDesc( &td);
td.BindFlags = 0;
td.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
td.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
```

Do not set td.Format and td.MiscFlags.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get a screenshot of your own app, or of the desktop?
If it's another app, how did you get its swap chain?
If you're using Windows 8+, you can get a screenshot of the desktop using the [Desktop Duplication API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404487(v=vs.85).aspx)

BTW, you can pass the flag D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG when creating the device (D3D11CreateDevice or D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain) and then inspect the debugging output. It might give you some important clues.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. took soo long to get back here. Takin' screenshot from other app with DLL injection. Surprisingly, Windows legitimately allows it